# Can I use an Xbox one controller for audio headset

Tags: sound, audio-jack, xbox-one

Can a single Xbox One controller be used as an audio output, via the controllers headset connection? If so will an afterglow brand controller make a difference?

Comment: It looks like this should work for the sound issue https://github.com/medusalix/xone  Which I got from this source https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361668/xbox-wireless-headset-usb-dongle.  I'm also including this source as well: https://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-xbox-one-controller-ubuntu/  I'm uncertain about the afterglow you mention.

Comment: I just asked this and found the solution as marked in the above comment, [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376220/way-to-use-the-xbox-one-controller-audio-jack/1376235#1376235) are my steps