# Xbox wireless headset (USB dongle)

Tags: drivers, sound, xbox-one

Has anyone tried one of those USB dongles + wireless headsets for Xbox consoles on Ubuntu flavored distros?

My headset: PDP Gaming lvl 50 wireless XB1

The USB dongle is being recognized as a gamepad:

```
[ 1305.661894] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 1305.997475] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0e6f, idProduct=0234, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 1305.997484] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1305.997488] usb 1-3: Product: PDPGaming LVL50 Wireless for XboxOne (Dongle)
[ 1305.997491] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Performance Designed Products
[ 1305.997530] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 0000D1A4CAEC2C2A
[ 1306.005329] input: **Generic X-Box pad** as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input30
```

Of course, not listed on sound devices.Any clue on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing https://github.com/medusalix/xone
Reading the readme seem that the Wireless dongle is not currently supported, but for me it worked.

Comment: I install xone and work perfectly, but only for a minute and then the handset goes off. I guess Xone believes it's a gamepad and by not detecting activity, it turns it off.

Comment: If you connect it via USB-C it also doesn’t recognize being used so it turns off after a minute or so.