# Way to use the xbox one controller audio jack?

Tags: sound, input-devices, xbox-one

I have an xbox one controller connected via USB and i would like to know if there is a way to make the controller's audio jack work with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.

First, i downloaded [THIS](https://github.com/medusalix/xone) git hub code as zip and unzipped the folder.

Then i went inside the unzipped folder, right click on a blank area and select > open in terminal

[image]

Finally, run the command

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Small EDIT:

It seems that this installation is causing some issues once in a while. Sometimes i turn on my pc with the controller and headphones connected and videos does not play, if i switch to speakers, the videos works correctly....